# Providing argument to a command after substitution

Tags: bash, escape-characters

I am trying to take a filename from the `~/Pictures` folder and supply it as an argument for the `nomacs` command. The filename contains some spaces, so I am using Bash substitution to escape spaces (I also want to take last file in the folder).

The code:

```
names=$(\ls ~/Pictures * | tac) 
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
names=($names)
IFS=$SAVEIFS
screenshot=~/Pictures/${names[0]}
screenshot=${screenshot// /\\ }
nomacs $screenshot
```

Example of the filename: `Screenshot from 2017-09-13 18-05-42.png`

The problem is that `nomacs $screenshot` does not work but when I execute `nomacs Screenshot\ from\ 2017-09-13 18-05-42.png`, it works as expected.

Should I use some special Bash technique for escaping spaces?

Comment: It is generally a [really bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse the output of `ls`.  You should probably look into either using `find` or simple shell globbing to get your list of files to process.  Extensive further reading on the subject can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).  Further, what specifically do you mean by 'last' file in the directory?  Most recent? Last lexically? Last in character sort order? Last modified?  What if this 'last' file is a directory?

Comment: if you're using ls to get the most recent or oldest file, there are also other Q's on here for doing that in various shells

Comment: Then you're still parsing `ls`, which is a bad idea that should make you feel bad.

Comment: Did you mean to say `ls ~/Pictures/*` there? Otherwise you're getting an ls of ~/Pictures and of *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather from your script, you're reversing the output of `ls` and selecting the first item. Here's a different way to do that with bash:

```
files=(~/Pictures/*)
nomacs "${files[-1]}"
```

This fills an array with the glob expansion of `~/Pictures/*` then passes the last element to the `nomacs` program.